# Java: Why's this For-Loop thousands of times slower?

Tags: java, performance, loops, profiling

So I have a simple method I'm calling millions of times a second, and I noticed that it was taking 16% of all processing time!!

The offensive routine is as follows:

```
public void placeHolder(){
    for (i2 = mnY; i2 < mxY; i2++){
        runInternalLoop();
    }
}
```

Coming in with a self-time of 27015ms, or 14.5% (Excluding further method calls)

Horrified, I switched to this instead:

```
 public void placeHolder(){
    i2 = mnY;
    runInternalLoop();
    i2++;
    runInternalLoop();
    if(i2<mxY){
        i2++;
        runInternalLoop();
    }
}
```

Now the self-time is 0ms! Literally from 15% of execution to nothing, for the exact same result.

What's the cause behind this madness?

Comment: hmm... you should single step thru the latter in the debugger.  Hint: it won't take long.

Comment: What do you mean Single-Step?

Comment: You've discarded the for-loop, that's why it's so fast.

Comment: Barring constraints that you've neglected to mention, these two programs are _completely_ different. Can you explain why you're so surprised that they would take different durations to execute?

Comment: @thebest108 Erik is referring to a step by step debugger (provided in any good IDE for example netbeans).It allows you to watch the codes execution step by step (it's a very useful tool)

Answer (score 7):

Your second version looks like an attempt at expanding a `for` loop, but unfortunately it's entirely inaccurate. The outcome is that it is about as far from "the exact same result" as could be.

It sort of only runs *one* iteration regardless of the input variables, although within that iteration you're running the "loop body" several times in odd places.

I recommend reviewing what a `for` loop does.